# XML sorting/formatting tool

Tags: xml, formatting

Is there any tool that can (pretty-print) format XML file as well as sort both its elements and attributes?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9161934/492 ..  but the answers here were more useful for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found this post: http://www.biglist.com/lists/xsl-list/archives/200106/msg01225.html that uses the following XSLT to indent XML and also sort attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Sort the attributes by name. -->
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:sort select="name( . )"/>
        <xsl:copy/>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()|comment()|processing-instruction()">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I haven't tried it yet, but most likely I will stick to XSLT to do formatting for me.

Comment: This is great to order xml attributes, how can I also order childs of a tag?

Comment: pefect solution. it sorts all attributes in alphabetical order. thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I was looking for a similar utility and didn't really find what I was looking for, so I just barely wrote one instead. It's very simple (and doesn't include attributes in node sorting), but works.

Maybe it'll be useful to others.. It's on [GitHub](https://github.com/kodybrown/sortxml).

Here's a bit from the GitHub page...

```
USAGE: sortxml.exe [options] infile [outfile]

  infile      The name of the file to sort, etc.
  outfile     The name of the file to save the output to.
              If this is omitted, then the output is written to stdout.

OPTIONS:

  --pretty    Ignores the input formatting and makes the output look nice.
  --sort      Sort both the nodes and attributes.
  --sortnode  Sort the nodes.
  --sortattr  Sort the attributes.

(prefix an option with ! to turn it off.)
```

The default is to output pretty and sorted nodes and attributes. Here is an example:

```
> type sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><root><node value="one" attr="name"/></root>

> sortxml.exe sample.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <node attr="name" value="one" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 14):

I liked this tool: https://github.com/MikeFoden/XmlSorter

You can sort by tag name and attributes. I like to use it before comparing some XML files.

[image: XML Sorter main window]

Comment: This wouldn't even load the XML file. Got a "Invalid XML" error. Couldn't handle the doctype tag. Once removed it workded.

Comment: This worked for me for a quick test of a pair of files with over 7K lines of and having a semi-complex xml structure, so I'm initially impressed. No errors at all. A smooth/quick download, launch and execution. One thing of note is that it allows "sort attributes" and "sort specific attributes" and where you then pick ones you want. You can check both options which seem overlapping.

Comment: It's "Sort attributes" and "Sort *by* specific attributes", very different. The first orders the attributes for each line, the second sorts all lines by the content of a specific attribute. The latter is very practical I think.

Comment: seems that CodePlex will shutdown soon, the page still on webarchive but the project archive is not linked to the page, so this is the link for the project archive in webarchive https://web.archive.org/web/20210309105113/https://codeplexarchive.blob.core.windows.net/archive/projects/XmlSorter/XmlSorter.zip

Comment: codeplex is down now for sure, link provided in comment before still works.

Comment: XmlSorter moved from Codeplex to Github: https://github.com/MikeFoden/XmlSorter

Answer (score 7):

Out of frustration with Visual Studio which seems to reorder & rewrite EDMX-files (Entity Framework) all the time (see also this [Uservoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4142937-sort-and-autoformat-xml-inside-edmx-files-before)), I wrote some Linqpad-code to reorder stuff.  It is is however easy (and obvious) to use outside of LinqPad.

It orders the elements by element-type (tag), then by the value of the element-attribute "Name", and then by some other stuff to try to make it sort of deterministic (different xml, but same meaning, is [usually] same output - see code).

It also orders the attributes.  Note that *semantically* XML-attributes may have no (relevant) order, but *textually* they do, and version control systems still consider them plain text...

(Note that it does not fix the different aliases, mentioned in [Entity Framework edmx file regenerating differently amongst team](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598795/entity-framework-edmx-file-regenerating-differently-amongst-team))

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"\\filepath1\file1.edmx");

    var orderedElements = CopyAndSortElements(xdoc.Elements());

    var newDoc = new XDocument();
    newDoc.Add(orderedElements);
    newDoc.Save(@"\\filepath1\file1.Ordered.edmx");
}

public IEnumerable<XElement> CopyAndSortElements(IEnumerable<XElement> elements)
{
    var newElements = new List<XElement>();
    // Sort XElements by Tag & name-attribute (and some other properties)
    var orderedElements = elements.OrderBy(elem => elem.Name.LocalName) // element-tag
                                  .ThenByDescending(elem => elem.Attributes("Name").Count()) // can be 0, more than 1 is invalid XML
                                  .ThenBy(elem => (elem.Attributes("Name").Any() ? elem.Attributes("Name").First().Value.ToString() : string.Empty))
                                   // in case of no Name-Attributes, try to sort by (number of) children
                                  .ThenBy(elem => elem.Elements().Count())
                                  .ThenBy(elem => elem.Attributes().Count())
                                  // next line may vary for textually different but semantically equal input when elem & attr were unordered on input, but I need to restrain myself...
                                  .ThenBy(elem => elem.ToString());
    foreach (var oldElement in orderedElements)
    {
        var newElement = new XElement(oldElement.Name);
        if (oldElement.HasElements == false && string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldElement.Value) == false)
        {
            // (EDMX does not have textual nodes, but SO-users may use it for other XML-types ;-) )
            // IsNullOrEmpty-check: not setting empty value keeps empty-element tag, setting value (even empty) causes start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag
            // (empty-element tags may be a matter of taste, but for textual comparison it will matter!)
            newElement.Value = oldElement.Value;
        }
        var orderedAttrs = oldElement.Attributes().OrderBy(attr => attr.Name.LocalName).ThenBy(attr => attr.Value.ToString());
        newElement.Add(orderedAttrs);
        newElement.Add(CopyAndSortElements(oldElement.Elements()));
        newElements.Add(newElement);
    }
    return newElements;
}
```

PS: We ended up using an XSLT, which somebody else wrote at the same time.  I think it fitted easier/better in everybody's build process.
But maybe/hopefully this is of some use to somebody.

Comment: What xslt did you end up using?

Comment: uh, watch this - it strips the values from nodes like `<thing> value </thing>`

Comment: @CADbloke, I added some code for usage with textual values in nodes.

Comment: @StevenT.Cramer, sorry, I just noticed your question now, and I don't remember.

Answer (score 0):

I came accross this post when trying to figure out how to sort and edmx file.
My solution was based on the Arvo Bowens solution found
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19324438/212241

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\git\Nvision\Source\NvisionEntities\NvisionModel.edmx");
    Sort(xdoc.Root);
    xdoc.Save(@"C:\git\Nvision\Source\NvisionEntities\NvisionModel.edmx");
}

public void Sort(XElement source, bool bSortAttributes = true)
{
    //Make sure there is a valid source
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

    //Sort attributes if needed
    if (bSortAttributes)
    {
        List<XAttribute> sortedAttributes = source.Attributes().OrderBy(a => a.ToString()).ToList();
        sortedAttributes.ForEach(a => a.Remove());
        sortedAttributes.ForEach(a => source.Add(a));
    }

    //Sort the children IF any exist
    List<XElement> sortedChildren = source.Elements().OrderBy(elem => elem.Attributes("Name").Any() ? elem.Attributes("Name").First().Value.ToString() : string.Empty).ToList();
    if (source.HasElements)
    {
        source.RemoveNodes();
        sortedChildren.ForEach(c => Sort(c));
        sortedChildren.ForEach(c => source.Add(c));
    }
}
```