# Add xml nodes from file into existing xml file

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am not experienced with LinQ and Xml. I need to join two xml files as follows

**file1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootNode>
<SubNode>

<NodeA id="1" />
<NodeB id="2" />
<NodeC id="3" />

</SubNode>
<LonelyNode/>
</RootNode>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootNode>
<SubNode>

<NodeD id="1" />
<NodeE id="2" />
<NodeF id="3" />

</SubNode>
<LonelyNode/>
</RootNode>
```

**actual code**

```
string fileName1 = "file1.xml";
string fileName2 = "file2.xml";

string filePath_file1 = String.Format("{0}{1}", rootDirectory, fileName1);
string filePath_file2 = String.Format("{0}{1}", rootDirectory, fileName2);

// create xml document from file1.xml
var document = XDocument.Load(filePath_file1.xml);

// add file2.xml
document.Root.Add(XDocument.Load(filePath_file2).Root.Elements());
Console.WriteLine(document);
Console.ReadLine();
```

**actual output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootNode>

<SubNode>
  <NodeA id="1" />
  <NodeB id="2" />
  <NodeC id="3" />
</SubNode>
<LonelyNode/>

<SubNode>
  <NodeD id="1" />
  <NodeE id="2" />
  <NodeF id="3" />
</SubNode>
<LonelyNode/>

</RootNode>
```

**wanted output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RootNode>
<SubNode>

<NodeA id="1" />
<NodeB id="2" />
<NodeC id="3" />
<NodeD id="1" />
<NodeE id="2" />
<NodeF id="3" />

</SubNode>
<LonelyNode/>
</RootNode>
```

How can I be specific of node to copy to first file ? I want to copy `<SubNode>` content only from file2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, instead of adding to `Root` find `SubNode` element using `Element` method and then add elements from other document.

```
document.Root
        .Element("SubNode")
        .Add(XDocument.Load(filePath_file2).Root.Element("SubNode").Elements());
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N8Sbxz)

**Output:**

```
 <RootNode>
  <SubNode>
    <NodeA id="1" />
    <NodeB id="2" />
    <NodeC id="3" />
    <NodeD id="1" />
    <NodeE id="2" />
    <NodeF id="3" />
  </SubNode>
  <LonelyNode />
</RootNode>
```

Comment: It works, thank you! it is also possible to sort the SubNode content by node name (NodeA, NodeB, ... ) ?

Comment: I found solution for sorting here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3469801/sorting-all-the-elements-in-a-xdocument thank you