# Can we automatically add a child element to an XElement in a sortable manner?

Tags: c#, sorting, xelement

I have seen this similar question on sorting `XElement` data ([Sorting all the elements in a XDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3469801/2287576)).

In my case I am only interested in the **first level** of children of the **root node** in the `XDocument` being sorted. But, assume that the data is **already sorted** and I now want to add a new element. Eg:

```
<Root>
    <A>...</A>
    <C>...</C>
    <D>...</D>
</Root>
```

So if I want to:

- Add an element called `B` I want to insert it after `A`.
- Add an element called `E` it should be added to the end.

The latter is easy because we can simply `Add`. Is there any way to insert the element at the right location automatically without resorting the whole list of nodes?

---

The suggested duplicate is not the same because they are stating where to put in. In my case we don't know. I have in mind a sortable collection where adding items is automatically sorted.

Comment: @KlausGütter No. In that scenario you are stating where to put in yourself. My scenario needs to work like a sorting container collection.

Comment: There is nothing built-in, but it should be easy to first find the first element with tag > tag_to_be_inserted and then apply the method in the linked answer.