# Entity Framework edmx file regenerating differently amongst team

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

We're having a lot of trouble with updating from database in our EDMX file.  Whenever one of our team members updates it, it blows up for the rest of us.

Here's an example diff:

```
<End Role="halo_forms" Type="Halo2Model.Store.halo_forms" Multiplicity="1" />
<End Role="halo_form_notes" Type="Halo2Model.Store.halo_form_notes" Multiplicity="*" />
```

becomes

```
<End Role="halo_forms" Type="Self.halo_forms" Multiplicity="1" />
<End Role="halo_form_notes" Type="Self.halo_form_notes" Multiplicity="*" />
```

Notice how it replaces Halo2Model.Store. with Self.?  We've both checked out the same code.

Another example, where it rearranges the order of parameters:

```
<Property Name="id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
```

becomes

```
<Property Name="id" Type="int" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" Nullable="false" />
```

To me this all looks like somehow we're using a different version of the edmx generator, but I'm struggling to find the documentation that would help explain it.  I haven't verified yet, but was wondering if these xml files being out of sync could be the issue?  How could these xml files get out of sync, and how do we prevent that from happening?

- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, Update 4
- v4 .NET Framework
- All on the EF 6.x EntityObject Generator for C# v 1.0.1.0 Extension

Developer 1:

- System.Data.Entity.xml, Last Modified: 1/10/2010 9:09pm
- System.Data.xml, 1/10/20120 9:09pm
  [image]

Developer 2:

- System.Data.Entity.xml, Last Modified: 12/12/2011 10:55AM
- System.Data.xml, 6/15/2012 2:01pm

UPDATE: Tried overwriting my xml files with those from a team member, and that did not solve the issue with the edmx generation.

Comment: That XML document is for documentation - i don't see how that could cause your EDMX to "blow up".  By "blow up", what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @BrendanGreen Updated to clarify. Makes it a huge pain in source control because these are illegitimate changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had installed the latest version of the Entity Framework 6.1.1 Tools for Visual Studio 2012, described as the first step to get Entity Framework here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/ee712906

Although I couldn't figure out the version history for the tools themselves, once we upgraded the whole team to that version, we stopped having issues.